# Proving the existence of consecutive pandigital multiples of a pandigital number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In the question, pandigital number is a number that contains each of 10 digits (from $0$ to $9$) at least once.

1. Prove that there is a positive integer $a$ so that $a,2a,3a,...,2021a$ are all pandigital numbers.
2. Is there a positive integer $a$ such that all positive multiples of $a$ (including $a$) are pandigital?

Can you help me with this question? I don't have any idea how to prove.

Answer (score 2):

For the first part, first show that for every $n$ there is a pandigital number divisible by $n.$ This is easy, because in fact by pigeonhole argument you can show that there is a multiple of $n$ whose leading digits are $1234567890$. Call one of these pandigital numbers divisible by $n$ $p_n,$ and let $q_n = \frac{p_n}n.$ Now, $q_1, \dotsc, q_{2021}$ with a goodly number of zeros in between will give you the solution to the first question. For the second question, note that if $N$ is relatively prime to $10,$ then there is a multiple of $N$ all of whose digits are $9.$ (so not very pandigital). What about $N$ *not* relatively prime to $10?$

Comment: I couldn't understand what do you mean by goodly number of zeros in between them. I even didn't get why you switched to q1, ... q2021. if our pandigital number is p_n, then 2021 multiples of p_n must be pandigital, why did you divide p_n to n. I was expecting you would multiply p_n by 2, 3, 4, ... 2021. Moreover, I understand that any n that is relatively prime with 10 cannot satisfy, but could not get the other case. "What about N not relatively prime to 10?" Is it clear. I mean does there exist such N to satisfy our condition and N is not relatively prime to 10?

Comment: Can you explain it, please?

Comment: @MiguelAngelCorrales I am dividing $p_n$ by $n$ so the multiple of the number by $n$ will have a $p_n,$ which is pandigital. A goodly number of zeros means you have enough zeros between $p_n/n$ blocks so that when you multiply by numbers up to (in your case) 2021, they don't run into each other.